# How to Post Enum data in Postman with form-data type

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I've tried searching Google but the answer is irrelevant, what I want to ask is how to Post enum data in Postman.

i currently work in node js with express framework, and i try to modeling my mongoose with multiple reference with enum

but, honestly i always fail when to hit the endpoints

this is my code

```
fieldBookedIDs: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        // Instead of a hardcoded model name in `ref`, `refPath` means Mongoose
        // will look at the `onModel` property to find the right model.
        refPath: 'fieldBookedID'
    },
    fieldBookedID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Player', 'Community']
    },
```

{

the result is

```
    "error": {
        "message": "field validation failed: fieldBookedIDs: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ fieldBookedID: [ '12234553fscdf', '15454asdasd' ] }\" at path \"fieldBookedIDs\", fieldBookedID: Path `fieldBookedID` is required."
    }
}
```

thank you for helping :)

[this is an image for my postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XLq6.png)